Deployment Error while deploying Custom field
I m trying to depploying the custom field from one sandbox to another sandbox via git but unfortunatly geeting below error.

i m verified the all field like profile permissions, etc etc but no luck.
Any help is much appriciated.
Regards
Brahma D

I think you need to contact support about that. It doesn't give us enough information to be able to help you

You would need to provide the metadata folder structure, and the content of the metadata files, as part of the question for us to be able to have a chance at helping. Think about what detail you would want if someone posed you the question. You can [edit] to add more detail.

Seen this issue in past and based on gack id, kindly disable field history tracking in package.xml and set to false for particular custom field and that should fix the issue.

Thank you Vinay. you solution worked out . after diabling the field tracking history deployment successfully completed. but i have small Query, can't we deploy new custom  with field history enbale  bcz we did it in past without any issue. Thanks again Vinay

@BRAHMAREDDY Yes you can deploy custom field with field history enable and seem like issue is reproducible only in few scenario's.  I was unable to replicate the issue.  Will be posting same as an answer

As mentioned in above,  Disable field history tracking in package.xml and set to false for custom field and try to deploy.  It should be deployed successfully in destination org without any issues.
